# Faulty Line coverage(100%) in cobertura via ant?

Tags: code-coverage, cobertura

I'm using cobertura, but it is giving me 100% line coverage. It is showing only those lines of code which are executed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the sources (or make sure, that they are included), when you use the report task:

```
<cobertura-report format="html" destdir="${coveragereport.dir}" srcdir="${src.dir}" />
```

Reference: [cobertura-anttask](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/anttaskreference.html)

Otherwise cobertura cannot know, how many lines/classes actually exist and will report 100% coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the file **cobertura.ser** before running the tests.

https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/FAQ